# Seat booking logic for meteor react application

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs, meteor

I am working on a meteor booking application where I have a limited number of seats. My application can be used by many users in parallel so there is a possibility that two users try to book same seat. But as per business logic seats can never be overbooked. In Java, I could have restricted parallel booking using synchronized block. I don't have much experience in meteor/react so not sure what should be the right way to achieve this.

My current thought is to use a reactive boolean to create a lock so if the application gets two booking request then it process them synchronously and fail the second booking request. Since the seat will already be allocated in first request. But I am afraid whether I will get into any deadlock. So I am seeking your opinion/help to implement this in a proper way.

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: I'm assuming were talking `node.js`, as it appears `meteor` is using node.  Node is single threaded, so you can't get a true deadlock as such.  But what you could do is create a global promise, and every time you start a processes you set this promise to the current one, you can then `await`, or `then` this promise to make sure it doesn't start before the last one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming here your backend is node.js,  seen as your using meteor, you're already using NPM, so a backend using Node makes sense.

In this case let's say your using Express or KOA to handle your requests, you can simply chain your tasks using promises, this will force the tasks to execute linearly.

Below is a simple working example, if you run the snippet you will notice I'm adding tasks every 700ms, but the tasks can only be completed in 1000ms, but as you see there is not overlapping and tasks get done in order.

```js
const delay = (ms) => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, ms));

let lastTask = Promise.resolve();

async function addTask(txt) {
  const ptask = lastTask;
  lastTask = (async () => {
    await ptask;
    console.log(`starting task ${txt}`);
    await delay(1000);
    console.log(`done task ${txt}`);
  })();
}

async function test() {
  for (let l = 0; l < 5; l += 1) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`adding task ${l}`);
      addTask(l);
    }, l * 700);
  }
}

test();
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using pub/sub in your Meteor, the job is done. Your bookings are reactive on a first come first served basis. As long as your connection is on, when you write your first booking, the seat is taken.

E.g. (logic writing)

1 Publish your bookings within desired scope.

2.Subscribe on the client within the same scope.

3.If document bookedOn $exists (date of booking) make 'unbookable' / unclickable, make UX show the necessary colors/experience.

When one books it, all users online on the platform and viewing that component will get the update.

It would be a bit of an 'issue' if you wouldn't use pubs/subs but common ... you're on Meteor you should use the native reactivity of Meteor. Your boolean is Boolean(bookedOn) or just bookedOn.

Answer (score 1):

I think the meteor way to do it is to call meteor method, to than user occupies a seat.
In this method check if this seat is already occupied.
More info here:
https://forums.meteor.com/t/if-multiple-users-are-trying-to-access-one-method-of-meteor-methods-how-to-make-method-as-synchronous-to-use-one-user-only-at-a-time/24969/8

But methods from different clients runs concurrently on the server.
You'll have to use something like semaphore. The easiest way would be to write a lock in mongo and check if the lock is not exists for this seat. Later the lock can be destroyed by mongo with TTL https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/

You can read more about methods here https://guide.meteor.com/methods.html

To wrap it up, the pseudo code would be something like this:

accuireLock(userId, seatId); // will read lock, if it's free write it, then read again just in case. In anything fails it should throw error

takeSeat(userId, seatId);